# compare two table with row and column

Tags: php, mysql, join

1. I have two tables table1 and table2
2. In table1 fieldname is cert_no and in table2 fieldname is cer1,cert2,cert3,cert4,cert5
3. The value which was not in table2 (cer1,cert2,cert3,cert4,cert5) alone want to display
4. If both table has same value only transfile_file want to display

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM table1 
    WHERE folio = '123456' 
      AND cm_flag !='X' 
      AND certificate_no NOT IN
          (SELECT CONCAT(certno1,certno2,certno3,certno4,certno5,certno6,certno7,certno8,certno9,certno10) 
             FROM table2 
            WHERE tofolio = '123456'
          )
```

Comment: If it's not too late, I would recommend to change your table design.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE folio = '123456' AND cm_flag !='X' AND certificate_no NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(certno1,',',certno2,',',certno3,',',certno4,',',certno5,',',certno6,',',certno7,',',certno8,',',certno9,',',certno10) FROM table2 WHERE tofolio = '123456')
```

Comment: i tried this only first data alone checking(certno1) remaining all datas displaying

Answer (score 0):

If you use for example Microsoft SQL Server there is a function [EXCEPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms188055.aspx) that return the different rows between 2 tables with the same fileds (same name, same types and same positions). In Oracle there is MINUS operation that is the same of EXCEPT.

In MySQL does not implement a EXCEPT or MINUS operation which is a unfortunate as it can allow for better execution plans in some cases than the alternatives.

This is a valid aternative and more performing than use NOT IN operation: realize a join is the best solution in SQL.

```
enter code here
SELECT a.* 
FROM table1 as a 
LEFT JOIN table2 as b
ON a.tofolio = b.tofolio 
WHERE b.tofolio  IS NULL
```